# what this json must work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

hi i search alot for get a respone from php back and if that respone is ok do someting and if its false do something else(!!!!!!!! WHENE I HAVE OTHER OUTPUT FROM THAT PHP !!!!!!)
this is my index file

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p> click </p>
<input type="text" id="who">
<br>
<input type="text" id="why">
<div id="bg" align="center">
</div>
</body>
```

this is my JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        var who = $('input#who').val();
        var why = $('input#why').val();     
        $.post('file.php',{who:who,why:why},function(data) {
    if(data.success){
         alert(data.message);
    }
    else{ alert('ERROR:' + data.message);
    }
});




    });
});
```

and this is my file.php

```
<?php
$response = array('success' => 'true', 
    'code' => "jQuery('#bg').html('\"Javascript\", \"json\", \"PHP\"');");
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

my question :
1- why this is not work i get alert (error:undifined)
2- how i can get some result from that php file when its have other output 
like this:

```
<?php
echo "1";
echo "2";
echo "3";
and now echo that json
?>
```

thanks :(

Comment: omg man. usually better to put a smiley face at the end. :)

Comment: `data.success` should work at least although `alert(data.message)` will fail since there is no "message" in the data. Try sending a `Content-type: application/json` header from your PHP file, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why this is not work i get alert (error:undifined)

You have to tell jQuery that the response is JSON. You can do so by either passing `'json'` as forth parameter to [`$.post` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or by setting the correct response headers in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Alternatively you can parse the response yourself with [`jQuery.parseJSON` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

> how i can get some result from that php file when its have other output like this

There is no easy way. The response is not valid JSON anymore, so you have to parse it yourself somehow. You should avoid doing this and return everything as JSON.

Comment: `You have to tell jQuery`. Ehh no you don't, it makes a guess at the data type without explicitly telling what it is; the problem is really with the `"123"` in front of the JSON :)

Comment: @Jack: I don't think that jQuery tries to guess if the content type is set to HTML. At least that the source of many problems. Invalid data in the response was the second question and is unrelated to the first problem.